# Is it possible to stop the PyCharm debugger from exiting after an exception from Django shell?

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm

I started the PyCharm debugger with `python manage.py shell` so I could interactively debug my Django project. However, if I run into an error, the debugger just exits. If I run `python manage.py shell` directly in a terminal this is not an issue. The same error will happen, but it doesn't just kick me out of the shell.

Is there a way to have the same functionality while debugging in PyCharm?